# Typescript Generic List Type Narrowing

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling to understand why I'm getting an error with this code.

```
type Foo = "foo" | "FOO";
type Bar = "bar" | "Bar";

type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

function isFoo(f: FooBar): f is Foo {
  return f === "foo";
}

function isBar(b: FooBar): b is Bar {
  return b === "bar";
}

function convertToUpperCaseForm<T extends FooBar>(i: T): T {
  if (isFoo(i)) return "FOO";
  else return "bar";
}

function doSomething<T extends FooBar>(items: T[]): T[] {
  if (items.length === 0) return [];
  else if (items.length === 1 && isFoo(items[0])) return ["FOO"];
  else return items.map(convertToUpperCaseForm)
  /**
    * Return a list of the same type. If I put a list of Foo
    * in I want a list of Foo out.
    */
}
```

Basically I'm saying I have a list that takes a generic which is a type union. If the first item in that list is one of the types, return another object of that same type. However, this is giving me the error:

```
Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'"foo"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could
be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'FooBar'.
```

Now, the reason I think this should work is that with the `(isFoo(items[0]))` check we have confirmed that a list of type `T[]`'s first elemnt is of `type Foo`, ergo, T must be at least of `type Foo`, so returning "foo" is a legal return of `type T`.

Is this a bug in Typescript? Is there a way I can work around this without type assertions? I believe it's typesafe, but I know with these kinds of errors there's usually a good explanation.

EDIT1: This isn't a perfect example of what I have in my codebase. A few people have pointed out things that aren't issues in my codebase. Just know that this is the error I'm getting, I do need the generic, and I do need to return an object of the same type I put in.

Edit2: Updated code snippet to reflect my codebase. I'm getting the same error in the `convertToUpperCaseForm` function.

```
Type '"FOO"' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'"FOO"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could
be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'FooBar'.
```

I find this really odd because I was under the impression that this was a result of the Array index. if `convertToUpperCaseForm` receives an object of type Foo, it should allow me to return an object of type Foo.

Comment: I'm not saying that your example shouldn't work, but you may aswell return `items[0]` if you know that it is `foo`. You should also check if the array isn't empty before accessing any of its elements.

Comment: @MikeS. I have this in my codebase, this is just a minimal example. In my codebase I'm actually returning a list not just one item, so I check if the length is zero and return an empty list if it is.

Comment: I see, you should probably provide an actual [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because without background knowledge, a lot of suggestions/answers will just be "remove the generic"

Comment: Gothca, I'll modify my code snippet, thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking this is correct behaviour that TS is showing. This is a niche issue because it involves string unions rather than other types. For example if you had `interface Foobar { a: string }` and then `interface Foobarbaz extends Foobar { b: string }` and then tried to `return { a: 'abc' }` you would have a problem because `Foobarbaz` also requires `b` to be set so in that particular case even though T extends Foobar you can't narrow it down using `Foobar`

Answer (score 1):

why you need the genric if you already know the type?

```
type Foo = "foo";
type Bar = "bar";

declare type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

function isFoo(f: FooBar): f is Foo {
  return f === "foo";
}

function isBar(b: FooBar): b is Bar {
  return b === "bar";
}

function doSomething(items: FooBar[]): FooBar {
  if (isFoo(items[0])) return "foo";
  if (isBar(items[0])) return "bar";
  return items[0];
}

console.log(doSomething(["foo", "bar"]));
```

// bar

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to make a minimal reproducible example, this isn't my exact use. What I'm actually doing is checking to see if the list is of length 1, and checking the type to see if it's `Foo`, then returning `[foo]`, otherwise I make a new list. It has to be generic for this new list case, sometimes I want to pass a list of 10 Bar in and get some list of Bars out.

Comment: ok so the response should be FooBar[]

Comment: Why though? Either the list is of length 1 and the first type is Foo, then return a list of Foo (which satisfies the generic constraint). Alternatively, i want to return a list of the same type I put in, I don't want to put in a list of Bars then get back a list of FooBars.

In my codebase FooBar is actually `Arc | Line`, if I send in a list of both, I want to get back a list of both, but if I send in a list of Lines, I want to get back a list of Lines. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flaw in your logic (the signature is wrong):

```
function convertToUpperCaseForm<T extends FooBar>(i: T): T {
  if (isFoo(i)) return "FOO";
  else return "bar";
}
```

Let's say `i` is of type `"foo"`, meaning that `T` is `"foo"`. The function is supposed to return something of the same type, `T`, so `"foo"` but you returned `"FOO"` which is different from `"foo"`.

```
const i = "foo" // i: "foo"
convertToUpperCaseForm(i) // (i: "foo"): "foo"

function convertToUpperCaseForm<T extends FooBar>(i: "foo"): "FOO" {
```

So you cannot say it takes `T` and returns `T` because as you can see, there is a case where it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand. `FooBar` is not just `Foo | Bar`, it's actually `"foo" | "FOO" | "bar" | "Bar"`